# Given that the equation $ax + 4 = 3x - b$ has more than 1 solution, find the value of $(4a + 3b)^{20202020}$

Tags: linear-algebra, exponentiation

Find the value of $(4a + 3b)^{20202020}$
given that $ax + 4 = 3x - b$ has more than one solution

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: for the value to be computable, it must be one of $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE. $$ax+4=3x-b\\ax-3x=-b-4\\x(a-3)=-(b+4)$$when this equation has more than 1 solution ? .....   when both sides get zero.
$$x\times 0=0$$ has more than one solution

can you take over?

Comment: That was very Helpful ! I want to ensure that a  = 3 and b = -4, Thank you so much...